# Why doesn't Django recognize this in the template

Tags: python, django

I'd like to show my top level categories if the parent is equal to one. The topcats is a queryset that contains category items. However the code starred below is not working. It is not finding any `cat` items with `parent = 1`. Any idea why?

```
{% for cat in topcats %}
    **{% if cat.parent == 1 %}**
        <a href ="/x/{{cat.id}}/dir/"><h3>{{ cat.category }}</a></h3>
            {% for each in topcats %}
                 {% if each.parent == cat.id %}
                    <h5>{{ each }}</h5>
                 {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Note:** parent is a [`TreeForeignKey`](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/models.html#treeforeignkey-treeonetoonefield-treemanytomanyfield) in the database

Comment: I'd say `cat.parent` is a `django.db.models.Model` object. Does `{% if cat.parent.pk == 1 %}` work?

Comment: Maybe you need cat.parent.id if it s a ForeignKey?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! :-) @Chewie if you post as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Done. I've posted a better alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say `cat.parent` is a [model object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model).

This should work for you:

```
{% if cat.parent.pk == 1 %}
```

However, this is quite hackish, as the parent node's id does not necessarily have a value of `1`. The [is_root_node()](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/models.html#is-root-node) method is a better approach:

```
{% if cat.parent.is_root_node %}
```